# Can you edit register values when debugging dump files in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

I have a dump of a crash where the ESP is set to zero, so I need to change it to EBP in order to view the stack frames.

According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dfstwbe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it should be possible by tabbing and typing a new value. This doesn't work for me when debugging this dump file, using either Native Only or Mixed Mode debugging.

I've also tried entering this into the Immediate window:

```
ESP = EBP
```

Which results in,

```
Error writing registry value.
```

With WinDbg I can change the ESP and see the rest of the stack but then it says it can't find the .pdb files when I clearly specify where to find them.

It'd be so much easier if Visual Studio would just let me edit the ESP value.

Comment: Since you mentioned windbg, use the commands `!sym noisy;.reload` and then dump your stack. You should see a lot of messages telling you where windbg is looking for your .pdb files.

Comment: I'd used reload and noticed it was looking for <Path I Gave It>\<Some Stupid Hash>\<The PDB File>. There were dozens of them and I couldn't be bothered to create the subdirectories with the hashes for each. Eventually I found that if I didn't give it a path, it tried to look for the PDB under the location it would've been on if I was on the build machine, so I replicated that path and it finally found the PDBs. God I hate WinDbg.

Comment: Windbg's learning curve can be steep but it's a powerful and lightweight debugger.